# Suddenly entering a Latin string

Tags: windows, character

I'm using Lenovo's Thinkpad, windows 11.

In Visual Studio, Mysql Workbench and etc...,
English is entered well, but suddenly English and special characters are entered as Latin characters.

Like the next string

[usaual]

**public**

[suddenly]

**ｐｕｂｌｉｃ**

It was found to be Latin letters.
It works fine when I turn the program off, but it's annoying.

Tell me how...

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but most of the English alphabet *is* Latin letters (taken from the old Romano-Latin alphabet). When you say "Latin" what do you mean by that? That the font or typeface wasn't what you expected? In a case where there are graphical differences, please post screenshots of the the old expected result as well as the new unexpected.